# How can I disable OneNote from starting automatically?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-onenote

I once tried out OneNote in Windows 10, and I did not really need it. But since then, there is this annoying OneNote icon appearing on the taskbar. Even if I turn it off, it comes back after a reboot. How can I get rid of it?

(Apparently, there is "OneNote" and there is "OneNote for Windows 10". For some reasons, I have both of them on my Windows 10 PC. But the one I am having an issue with is "OneNote", most likely part of Office 365 that I don't have any subscription to. I was able to run it. I did not start the free trial.)

Comment: You can uninstall it from apps and features. It is installed per-windows-account basis.

Comment: I did that but it is still there because it was coming from my MS Office installation. But I don't want to uninstall Office.

Answer (score 17):

Open Task Manager, Startup Items and disable it there. That should normally work.

If not, get Autoruns (Microsoft SysInternals). Download it, install it (easy) and run it.

Disable all occurrences of One Note that show up in Autoruns.

That should do it.  All Windows 10 machines have One Note for Windows 10 and it is not running here.

Good luck.

Answer (score 13):

> But since then, there is this annoying OneNote icon appearing on the taskbar. Even if I turn it off, it comes back after a reboot. OneNote is not part of my Startup applications. How can I get rid of it?

1. Open OneNote and go to File > Options

[image]

2. Click on Display and then untick the `Place OneNote icon in the notification area of the taskbar` checkbox.

[image]

Comment: [I have made an educated assumption that the icon you want to get rid of is this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQZi0.png).  If that isn't the icon then you should edit your question and provide us which icon you are talking about.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. I want the start entry removed from my startup items. However, in my case. I don't have Office 365 subscription and I never did. For me, the "Option" is grayed out. So I can't get to the place to make the change.

Comment: You indicated you already checked the startup registry keys.  That’s the reason I didn’t suggest using Autoruns.  Your using the Desktop or UWP version? Edit your question instead of making this comment thread any longer

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy - That is handled by the startup key, which wasn’t and has nothing to do with the question that was asked, you might want to read the author’s question again.  My answer absolutely answers the author’s question, of course the author never did, provide additional clarification necessary to refine my answer.  My answer never claimed to prevent it from automatically starting up only get rid of the notification icon which is what the author wanted to prevent

Answer (score 4):

It is really easy, since you don't use it, all you have to do is uninstalling OneNote, after it is uninstalled it will never bother you again.

To open elevated PowerShell:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>→type `powershell`→<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then paste these codes into the resultant window:

```powershell
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Where {$_.Name -match "OneNote"} | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | Where {$_.DisplayName -match "OneNote"} | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online
```

Then the problem should be solved.